# Redirect wordpress from http to https. Subfolders problem

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I have problem with forcing a redirection from HTTP to HTTPS. In my .htaccess file I have following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And almmost everything works perfect. When I type in browser url: http://mypage.com everything is good, and adress is changing to http**s**:// but when I type for example: http://mypage.com/subpage redirection does not work. So the problem are subpages (but only with direct URL page visit) Any ideas how to fix that? This is WordPress page.

Comment: Sounds like you need to change the order if rewritings in your implementation. Place the redirection to https _bevor_ all other rewriting rules, so further up in your configuration. If you use multiple configuration files you also need to consider the order in which they are processed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I have in my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Las directivas (líneas) entre `BEGIN WordPress` y `END WordPress` se generan dinámicamente
# , y solo se deberían modificar mediante filtros de WordPress.
# Cualquier cambio en las directivas que hay entre esos marcadores se sobreescribirán.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# This domain inherits the “PHP” package.
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Test, copy and paste in YOUR .htaccess, in the general settings of wordpress you must configure everything with https in WordPress Address (URL) Site Address (URL).

Keep in mind that if you are migrating a web page from your localhost to an online server, all your urls must be replaced from http to https. Regards.